# What type of packet is 0x5577

Tags: cisco, ethernet, protocol-theory, packet-analysis

I've been trying to find out what type of packet is `0x5577`, based on this [page](http://csie.nqu.edu.tw/smallko/sdn/latency.htm). The following is a snapshot of the source code that indicates this values:

```
   f = myproto()
    f.timestamp = int(time.time()*1000 - start_time)
    #print f.timestamp
    e = pkt.ethernet()
    e.src=EthAddr("0:0:0:0:0:2")
    e.dst=EthAddr("0:1:0:0:0:1")
    e.type=0x5577  # What ethernet value is this?
    e.payload = f
    msg = of.ofp_packet_out()
    msg.data = e.pack()
    msg.actions.append(of.ofp_action_output(port=2))
    core.openflow.getConnection(src_dpid).send(msg)
```

I don't also find it in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType). I did Google search but without an answer! Has anyone seen this type of ethernet packet before?

Comment: Where did you get that number? If is is from the EtherType field of an ethernet frame, it is an unregistered EtherType.

Comment: @RonMaupin I have updated my post. As you said, can it be unregistered EtherType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an unregistered EtherType, so, it has no standard meaning or type. It appears that someone just made it up to use for a project. Anyone else could use that value for a different project, and it could mean something else. You will need to ask the person who wrote the code.

EtherTypes are [registered with the IEEE](https://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/tut/ethertype.pdf), and you can find the registered ones [here](http://standards-oui.ieee.org/ethertype/eth.txt). IANA also, maintains [an unofficial page](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ieee-802-numbers/ieee-802-numbers.xhtml) of EtherTypes.